# Question about convergence in the L^2 and L^1 norms.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces

Given that $f_n \in L^2([0,1])$, $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e. on $[0,1]$ and $||f_n||_2\leq 1$,

How would I show that  $||f_n-f||_1\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Would I need to first show that $f \in L^2([0,1])$? If so, would this come from $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e.?

I don't see how it's possible to jump from knowing something about the L^2 norm to the L^1 norm...
It seems like this implies that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^2[0,1]$ but I know that is not true.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Would it matter if $E$ was something other that $[0,1]$?

Comment: If $E$ has finite measure you can use holder's inequality

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I see what you mean, I am going to edit the post to clarify.

Comment: @rubikscube09 I'm not sure what I would be using Holder's inequality on since I have two different normed spaces, L^1 and L^2... Could you clarify?

Comment: In general, pointwise convergence does not imply convergence in norm (or vice versa)

Answer (score 2):

First, Fatou's lemma yields
$$\|f\|_2^2 \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|^2_2 \leq 1$$
Then, by Egorov's theorem for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a set $E_\epsilon$ such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $E_\epsilon$, and $m(E_\epsilon^c)<\epsilon$. Clearly, $\int_{E_\epsilon}|f_n-f| \to 0$, so it remains to study $\int_{E_\epsilon^c} |f_n-f|$. By Holder's inequality, we have

$$\int_{E_\epsilon^c} |f_n-f| \leq m(E_\epsilon^c)^{1/2}(\|f_n\|_2+\|f\|_2) \leq 2\epsilon^{1/2}$$

Notice that you need finiteness of the measure space to apply Egorov.